# link log and identity in GLMER

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, lognormal-distribution

Say that we have a GLM model with the following formula:
outcome = b1x1 + b2x2 + b0
and outcome is cost, x1, x2 are independent variables

Fitted using log link with gaussian distribution, so log normal. We would then have ratios of cost because we fitted it using log link function.

Would it be sensible to use that ratio to estimate the actual cost by multiplying it with the mean of the cost?

So, say ratio of cost = 1.2x1 + 1.1x2 + 1
then if the mean cost = 1000, cost at x1=1 would be approximately 1100 and cost at x1=0 would be 900?

Comment: Hi @user401679 - welcome to CV. Re "Fitted using log link with gaussian distribution, so log normal." - this isn't correct. The link function defines the relationship between the linear predictor and the _mean_. Not the distribution of the variable. So a log-link Gaussian GLM, is _distributed Gaussian_. However, the _mean_ of the log-link Gaussian will be positive, and scale multiplicatively with the linear predictor.